# Xamarin.Forms binding not updating the label ui

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms

I want to bind my label to my model which works fine but the actual value of the property does not get updated, I also implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Am I doing something wrong here?

My Model

```
public string ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString {
    get
    {
        
        return _ergebnisBasisPaketPreis = (BasisPaketPreis[(int) Basispaket] * (BasisPaketInterval + 1)).ToString("C0"); 
    }
    set
    {
        _ergebnisBasisPaketPreis = value;
        
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString));
    }
}
```

My Label:

```
<Label x:Name="LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall" 
       Text="{Binding ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString}" 
       Grid.Column="3" 
       VerticalOptions="Center"/>
```

And I am setting the binding context to my Content page.

ContentPage:

```
public partial class GeräteKonfiguration : ContentPage {

    public GeräteKonfiguration(User currentUser) {
        InitializeComponent();

        _currentUser = currentUser;
        Initialize();
    }

    private User _currentUser;
    private Gerät _currentGerät;

    private void Initialize() {

       
        _currentGerät = _currentUser.ServiceModuleAngebotObj.CurrentGerät;
        LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, _currentGerät.ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString);
        LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall.BindingContext = _currentGerät;
        BindingContext = _currentGerät;
        ToolBarView.BackButton.Clicked += BackButtonOnClicked;
        ToolBarView.BackButton.Text = "blabla";
        ToolBarView.TitleText = _currentGerät.Anwendung + " - " + _currentGerät.Antriebsart +
                                " - " + _currentGerät.Baureihe + " - " + _currentGerät.Typ;
        LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall.Text = _currentGerät.ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString;

    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to suggest to add `EmptyConverter` and check if binding is working.

Comment: the binding is working fine because my properties are getting the values, just the label does not display the current property value

Comment: Could you add code of your `ContentPage`?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Could you explain why are you setting binding in xaml and in code?

Comment: because i need it for multiple controls is there any other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your code behind is overwriting your binding by binding the label text to whatever the value of the property is.

```
LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, _currentGerät.ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString)
```

This isn't likely to be a valid binding path (which would be `ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString`), so the binding won't work.

You then get the correct initial value by setting it here:

```
LabelPreisBasispaketIntervall.Text = _currentGerät.ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString;
```

Remove both of these lines, and the binding should work - your XAML looks correct.

Secondly, your property getter doesn't use the value you set it to - you re-compute it each time.  Your property should probably just be:

```
public string ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString
{
    get { return _ergebnisBasisPaketPreisString; }
    set 
    {
        _ergebnisBasisPaketPreisString = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString));
    }
}
```

And you can set the initial computed value in the constructor.  Or stick to the computed property and raise the property changed in the dependent properties:

```
public string ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString
{
    get { return BasisPaketPreis[(int) Basispaket] * (BasisPaketInterval + 1)).ToString("C0"); }
}

public string Basispaket
{
    get { return _basispaket; }
    set 
    {
        _basispaket = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Basispaket));
         OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErgebnisBasisPaketPreisString));
    }
}

// and similar for the other properties that are used in the computation
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer i removed both of them , but as soon as i change the value of the property my Label still displayes the old value and not the new. Am i missing something?

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ I've updated, it also appears you property is wrong and will always return the same value.

Comment: i still cant get it to work... i need to calculate some propertys and update then the label do i calculate in get?

Comment: You can't set the property and have it computed at the same time. Pick one or the other. I've added the other option.